# Atomic Design Pattern - Business Logic

Tags: html, components, atomic-design

I am implementing Atomic Design pattern in my project. Just a quick question, in where distinct stage should i put the business logic if i implement atomic design pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atoms and Molecules shouldnt have any business logic. Maybe the molecules can have some event handlers for there buttons, but they shouldnt. Organisms can have logic, if needed. But if you really want to implement that pattern, than the container should handle all the logic (pages/templates) so called HOC, higher order components.

If you read more about it, [this article helped me a while ago](https://blog.usejournal.com/thinking-about-react-atomically-608c865d2262).
You could also read the book Atomic Design from Brad Frost, i used it in my master thesis as literature review.